# MySQL select query for stock management

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to get current stock from purchase and sale table but getting only one result.

Here is the query I wrote.

```
SELECT `I`.`id`, `I`.`modal`, `I`.`brand`, 
IFNULL(SUM(P.qty), 0) as p_qty, 
IFNULL(SUM(S.qty), 0) as s_qty, 
SUM(P.qty)-SUM(S.qty) as t_qty 
FROM `items` `I` 
    LEFT JOIN `purchase_details` `P` ON `P`.`item_id` = `I`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `sale_details` `S` ON `S`.`item_id` = `I`.`id` 
WHERE `I`.`id`
IN("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70") 
GROUP BY `P`.`item_id`
```

Expected result : All the items should come with or without zero according to stock.

Comment: Is the 'IN' statement you added there necessary?

Comment: Yes, because Items are not limited and predictable. if you have other way to do this, suggest me.

Comment: I'm just thinking - it's ok if there's always 70 items in your table, but if you add items to your stock, you'd need to add the ID to that statement for it to be included in the results. If not, you could omit the WHERE...IN... statement and it should work as expected too :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, which item (ID) does it return?

Comment: yes I know, these ids are coming dynamically. from one other query result.

Answer (score 1):

Try `GROUP BY I.id`

```
    SELECT
    `I`.`id`,
    `I`.`modal`,
    `I`.`brand`,
    IFNULL(SUM(P.qty),
    0) AS p_qty,
    IFNULL(SUM(S.qty),
    0) AS s_qty,
    SUM(P.qty) - SUM(S.qty) AS t_qty
FROM
    `items` `I`
LEFT JOIN
    `purchase_details` `P`
ON
    `P`.`item_id` = `I`.`id`
LEFT JOIN
    `sale_details` `S`
ON
    `S`.`item_id` = `I`.`id`
WHERE
    `I`.`id` IN(
        "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70"
    )
GROUP BY
    `I`.`id`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
    `I`.`id`,
    `I`.`modal`,
    `I`.`brand`,
    IFNULL((SELECT SUM(P.qty) FROM purchase_details `P` WHERE p.item_id = I.id),
    0) AS p_qty,
    IFNULL(SUM(S.qty),
    0) AS s_qty
FROM `items` `I`
LEFT JOIN `sale_details` `S` ON `S`.`item_id` = `I`.`id`
WHERE  `I`.`id`  BETWEEN 1 AND 70
GROUP BY I.id
```

Comment: It may work but I.id is not static. It will change all the time.

Comment: try removing `SUM(P.qty) - SUM(S.qty) AS t_qty`

Comment: I also try this thing. Actually I tried many thing than come here. I can't understand why it returns only one result.